# Why are 8 images formed for a object kept symmetrically between two mirrors kept at angle 50°?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, optics, reflection, geometric-optics

Let us consider two mirrors $M_1$ and $M_2$ kept at $50^\circ$ with each other.

An object $O$ is kept symmetrically between the mirrors making angles $25^\circ$ with each.

Now the number of images is given by the formula:

$$n = \frac{360}{\theta},$$

where is $n$ is odd. The number of images is $n$ for a asymmetrically placed object and $n-1$ for a  symmetrically placed object.

If $n$ is even, the number of images is $n-1$ for all positions of the object.

Applying the formula to this case we get

$$n=\frac{360^\circ}{50^\circ} = 7.2,$$

ignoring the decimal part. As the object is symmetrically placed, number of images becomes $n-1 = 6$.

But the ray diagram I have drawn shows otherwise.

[image: The ray diagram]

Here 8 images are formed. So which one should I follow, the ray diagram or the formula?

Comment: I think your problem is in _"ignoring the decimal part"_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formula

$$n = \frac{360^\circ}{\theta}$$

has on one side an integer and on the other a continuous variable. This should give you pause. For correctness, we may either restrict $\theta$ to precisely those values that give integral $n$ or modify the formula. So, for $50^\circ$, the formula doesn't hold.  Truncating the decimal isn't something the formula can do so it can't be expected to yield a right answer.

### Symmetric case

Let the angle made by the object with the x-axis be $\widetilde{\phi}$. Similarly, let the mirrors be at angles $-\phi$ and $\phi$ (reflective sides facing each other). Let $R_+(\widetilde{\phi})$ denote reflection of the object at angle $\widetilde{\phi}$ by the mirror at $\phi$. Similarly, define $R_-(\widetilde{\phi})$.

A simple analysis shows that

$$
R_\pm(\widetilde{\phi})=\pm2\phi-\widetilde{\phi}\tag{1}
$$

Note that $R_\pm(R_\pm(\widetilde{\phi}))=R_\pm^2(\widetilde{\phi})=\widetilde{\phi}$ i.e. reflection of the same reflection is identity. Hence the only sequences of operators that generate the images are

$$
+, -+,+-+,-+-+,\ldots\tag{2}\\  
-,+-,-+-,+-+-,\ldots
$$
where $-+$ denotes the reflection $R_-(R_+(\widetilde{\phi}))$.

Either sequence terminates when the image formed cannot be reflected any further - it has 'gone beyond' the extended mirror.

[image: image showing the eight reflections for phi equals 25 degrees]
*fig 1: The 8 reflections for $\phi=25^\circ, \widetilde{\phi}=0$. The object is the filled point in cyan. The thin, solid, light orange and light violet lines, starting at the object, connect the sequence of images resulting from the first and second sequences of eqn. 3, respectively. The thick orange and violet lines depict the reflective surface of the mirrors at $\phi$ and $-\phi$ resp., while the dashed lines are extensions. The hatch shading indicates the non-reflective side. The filled and unfilled points on the unit circle are the image points, colored according to the mirror that formed them.*

For the symmetric case ($\widetilde{\phi}=0$), the images are produced at angles

$$
+2\phi,-4\phi,+6\phi,-8\phi,\ldots\\
-2\phi,+4\phi,-6\phi,+8\phi,\ldots\\\tag{3}
$$

in other words at $\pm 2k \phi$, $k$ positive integer. The sequence terminates for the **first** $k$ such that

$$
\begin{align}
2k \phi &\ge \pi-\phi\tag{4.1}\\
\therefore k&=\left \lceil\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\pi}{\phi}-1\right)\right\rceil\tag{4.2}
\end{align}
$$

The number of images is then $2k$. Note that for integral $n=2\pi/\theta=\pi/\phi$,
$$
2k=
\begin{cases}
n&\text{even } n\\
n-1&\text{odd }n
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: Where does this extension for all angles come from? How is it derived?

Comment: @SrishDutta Hi!Sry about the late reply. The formula was an ad-hoc and obtuse construction, via analysing the possible values case-by-case while accomodating  the edge cases. I am sorry you had to read that - it was a pretty terrible formula (with a typo), the explanation wasn't clear, and used a shoe-horned indicator function; it was an old post, penned in some hurry I suppose, around the time I was starting out on PhySE - that I wrote once, posted, then forgot about. Again, apologies and thanks for bringing it to my attention; I have posted a sensible, explanatory and cleaned up correction.

Comment: Thank you so much - this helped a lot!